# Kafka integration with Ingres database

Tags: apache-kafka, ingres, adroitlogic

I am trying to integrate Ingres database with Kafka. What I am looking for is, as soon as a record gets inserted/updated/deleted in Ingres database, it should publish this record in a Kafka topic. Is there any such product/framework available which can achieve this?

There is some connector named "Kafka Ingress connector" available at
https://developer.adroitlogic.com/connectors/docs/17.07/kafka/kafka_ingress_connector.html 
But this doesn't seem to be for Ingres database. Notice the spelling difference. The database name is Ingres whereas the connector given on this website says Ingress. Even if I ignore the spelling difference, the webpage doesn't talk anything about Ingres database. It seems that the name "Kafka Ingress Connector" is given for some different purpose & it is not really intended for Ingres database.

I am expecting the real time integration between Ingres database & Kafka. If someone is aware of this, kindly let me know. 
Also, if someone from adroitlogic can confirm about Kafka Ingress connector, it would be great. Thank you!

Comment: I've never used Kafka sorry, but in case it helps, a quick web search suggests database connections can be made via JDBC; Ingres ships with a JDBC driver (and an ODBC driver also).

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any open-source connector. [HVR](https://www.hvr-software.com/solutions/real-time-data-integration-apache-kafka/) offers real-time data integration for Ingres and Kafka but I assume that you need to purchase a license to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any pre-made framework to do this, but it isn't difficult either.  The traditional architectural answer to these types of needs is to create a rule+procedure that posts the change to a queue, implemented as its own table, and raise an event.  You then create a simple C (or whatever) application that listens for the event, pulls records from the queue (table), and publishes to the consumer application, in this case Kafka.

(Ingress is a completely different thing, unrelated to the product Ingres)